# Sequelize populate joined table attributes

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a few tables and I want to do some includes on a joined table, but I can't seem to figure it out. Here are my models:

```
/* Staff model */

const model = {
  fisrName: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: { model: 'Roles', key: 'id' },
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: { model: 'Profiles', key: 'id' },
  }
};

const Staff = createModel('Staff', model, { paranoid: true });
export default Staff

/* Service model */
const model = {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  category: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  }
};

const Service = createModel('Service', model, {});

export default Service;

/* Appointment model */
const model = {
  endDate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  startDate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  day: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
};

const Appointment = createModel('Appointment', model, {})

Appointment.belongsToMany(Service, { through: 'Products', as: 'products' });

export default Appointment;

/* Products model */
const model = {
  serviceId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  appointmentId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  staffId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: { model: 'Staff', key: 'id' },
  }
};

const Product = createModel('Product', model, {});

Product.belongsTo(Staff, { foreignKey: 'staffId', as: 'staff' });

export default Product;
```

This is my appointment query, where I include the services array, and on this services array, I have a Products object, and in this object I have a staffId that I want to populate, and I'm not sure how. I have tried different ways, but nothing worked.

```
const appointment = await Appointment.findByPk(req.params.id, {
      include: [
        {
          model: Service,
          as: 'services',
          through: { attributes: { include: ['id', 'staffId', 'serviceId', 'appointmentId'], exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'AppointmentId', 'ServiceId'] },
        },
      ],
    });
```

And this is my response:

```
{
    "startDate": "date",
    "endDate": "date",
    "day": "date",
    "services": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Service name",
        "category": "service category",
        "description": "service description",
        "Products": {
            "id": 1,
            "staffId": 2,
            "serviceId": 1,
            "appointmentId": 1
        }
    }]
}
```

What I want is to do is to populate the ***staffId*** from ***Products*** with the model from the collection, something like this:

```
{
    "startDate": "date",
    "endDate": "date",
    "day": "date",
    "services": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Service name",
        "category": "service category",
        "description": "service description",
        "Products": {
            "id": 1,
            "staffId": {
                "firstName": "First Name",
                "lastName": "Last Name"
            },
            "serviceId": 1,
            "appointmentId": 1
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const appointment = await Appointment.findByPk(req.params.id, {
    include: [
        {
            model: Service,
            as: 'services',
            through: {
                attributes: { include: ['id', 'staffId', 'serviceId', 'appointmentId'], exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'AppointmentId', 'ServiceId'] },
            },
            include: [{
                as: 'Products', model: Product,
                include: 'staff'
            }]
        }
    ]
});
```